# can't save docker images

Tags: docker, centos

i can't save my docker images, when i try to save a container, it fails:

```
Error response from daemon: chtimes /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-616188241/947b32c6be7d631920d03730a39f6878b18bd6fad548baf5a0cf8fd59e34ef7f: invalid argument
```

here is docker log:

```
time="2016-04-28T11:25:29.819354407+04:30" level=info msg="GET /v1.21/images/get?names=jenkins" 
time="2016-04-28T11:25:30.001454111+04:30" level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.21/images/get returned error: chtimes /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-206252912/2f86385bd2bb77c88bcbefdb8d9b69824b5b16e419fc6023462312df97451b01: invalid argument" 
time="2016-04-28T11:25:30.001689438+04:30" level=error msg="HTTP Error" err="chtimes /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-206252912/2f86385bd2bb77c88bcbefdb8d9b69824b5b16e419fc6023462312df97451b01: invalid argument" statusCode=500
```

the same problem was reported in docker github and the solution was adding validate timestamp, but i don't know how to do that and i can't find a way, my kernel is updated. and docker version is `1.9.1`
what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [issue 20324](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20324#issuecomment-203534335), try first to:

- [upgrade docker to 1.11 (on CentOS)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/)
- run your container again
- try and save it to see if the issue persists